# How to loop through an array of dynamic form inputs and insert them into more than one table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, insert

I have a master form for inserting recipes into a database. Most of the form is working except for being able to insert more than one ingredient into the database.

I think I need an array to hold the ingredient inputs (ingredient_name, amount, measurement type) and then to somehow loop through that array as many times as it has been filled out (user can click an 'add new ingredient' button and jquery adds a new set of inputs). I could probably figure this out on my own as this has been asked before, but...

**...the real problem I'm having is that the 'ingredient_name' input needs to be inserted into one table (ingredients) and the 'amount' and 'measurement type' inputs need to be inserted into another table (ingredientLists). I have no idea how to do this.**

```
<input type="text" name="ingredient_name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount" value="" />
<select name="measurement_ID" value=""> 
   <option value="14" >n/a</option> 
   <option value="1"  >teaspoon</option> 
   <option value="2"  >tablespoon</option> 
   <option value="3"  >fluid ounce</option> 
   <option value="4"  >cup</option> 
   <option value="5"  >pint</option> 
   <option value="6"  >quart</option> 
   <option value="7"  >pound</option> 
   <option value="8"  >ounce</option> 
   <option value="9"  >milligram</option> 
   <option value="10" >gram</option> 
   <option value="11" >millimeter</option> 
   <option value="12" >centimeter</option> 
   <option value="13" >inch</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure if I can even process it correctly using the form set-up I have now.

This is what I have processing the ingredient inputs so far (this set-up only allows the first ingredient to be entered into the database).

```
                $recipe_id = $pdo->lastInsertId('recipe_ID');

                //inputs inserted into ingredient table
                $query2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ingredients (ingredient_name) VALUES (?)');
                $query2->bindValue(1, $ingname);

                $query2->execute();

                $ingredient_id = $pdo->lastInsertId('ingredient_ID');

                //inputs inserted into ingredient list table
                $query3 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ingredientLists (recipe_ID, ingredient_ID, amount, measurement_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
                $query3->bindValue(1, $recipe_id);
                $query3->bindValue(2, $ingredient_id);
                $query3->bindValue(3, $amount);
                $query3->bindValue(4, $measure);

                $query3->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to submit multiple lines you need to put them in an array (note the brackets after the name)

```
<input type="text" name="ingredient_name[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
<select name="measurement_ID[]"> 
<option value="14" >n/a</option> 
<option value="1"  >teaspoon</option> 
<option value="2"  >tablespoon</option> 
<option value="3"  >fluid ounce</option> 
<option value="4"  >cup</option> 
<option value="5"  >pint</option> 
<option value="6"  >quart</option> 
<option value="7"  >pound</option> 
<option value="8"  >ounce</option> 
<option value="9"  >milligram</option> 
<option value="10" >gram</option> 
<option value="11" >millimeter</option> 
<option value="12" >centimeter</option> 
<option value="13" >inch</option>
</select>
```

When posted to your php script they will be arrays that you can loop through.

```
$ingredient_name=$_POST['ingredient_name'];
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$measurement_ID=$_POST['measurement_ID'];
for($i=0;$i<=count($ingredient_name);$i++) {
if (isset($ingredient_name[$i])){
//do your insert queries here you can insert to any tables you need to.
//the variables are accessed like this $ingredient_name[$i] 
}
}
```

Below is using your code

```
$recipe_id = $pdo->lastInsertId('recipe_ID');

$ingname=$_POST['ingredient_name'];
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$measure=$_POST['measurement_ID'];

for($i=0;$i<=count($ingname);$i++) {
if (isset($ingname[$i])){
$query2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ingredients (ingredient_name) VALUES (?)');
$query2->bindValue(1, $ingname[$i]);
$query2->execute();
$ingredient_id = $pdo->lastInsertId('ingredient_ID');

$query3 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ingredientLists (recipe_ID, ingredient_ID, amount, measurement_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$query3->bindValue(1, $recipe_id);
$query3->bindValue(2, $ingredient_id);
$query3->bindValue(3, $amount[$i]);
$query3->bindValue(4, $measure[$i]);
$query3->execute();
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, that seems simple enough. Is that it, though? I'll still have to enter the ingredient_name into one table (ingredients) and the amount and measurement into another table (ingredientLists). Then I'm pulling the lastInsertID from the ingredient table (relating to the ingredient_name just entered) and inserting it to the ingredientLists table in the same row as the amount and measurement just entered.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track based on your feedback, but it still isn't working. I'll post below what I tried.

Comment: I tried using this and it still isn't entering any inputs to the ingredient table or the ingredientLists table. Why does this only count the ingname and check if the ingname is set? Shouldn't it also check for the amount and measurement values?

Comment: You can check if you want. Did you change your html like with the brackets after the name? If the ingredient_name isn't an array then the loop won't run. When you post can you print_r($_POST) and put the results here?

Comment: Yes, I added the brackets to the form. Here is the entire form submission printed out. Array ( [name] => My Recipe [category_ID] => 1 [ingredient_name] => Array ( [0] => orange [1] => apple ) [amount] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 ) [measurement_ID] => Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 14 ) [servings_ID] => 9 [prep_hours] => [prep_minutes] => [cook_hours] => [cook_minutes] => [oven_temp] => [directions] => Direction notes here [extra_comments] => Extra notes here )

Comment: Ok, so now this back to processing just the first ingredient (to the database) that the user enters, even though the whole array prints out correctly. @Funk Doc

Comment: I posted where the code is right now. Maybe there are syntactical errors? I'm not too familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Took out the queries and pdo stuff.

```
                $ingname     = $_POST['ingredient_name'];
                $amount      = $_POST['amount']; //ingredient amount
                $measure     = $_POST['measurement_ID']; //ingredient measurement


                for($i=0;$i<=count($ingname);$i++) {
                    if (isset($ingname[$i])){
                        print_r($_POST['ingredient_name']);
                    }
                }
```

When I print the array containing the ingredient names, this is the result. It just repeats the array four times, since I entered four ingredients. I'm not sure if this is good or bad.

```
Array ( [0] => cookies [1] => candy [2] => chocolate [3] => cake ) Array ( [0] => cookies [1] => candy [2] => chocolate [3] => cake ) Array ( [0] => cookies [1] => candy [2] => chocolate [3] => cake ) Array ( [0] => cookies [1] => candy [2] => chocolate [3] => cake )
```

Comment: Just count 1 variable not this for($i=0;$i<=count($ingname, $amount, $measure);$i++) this for($i=0;$i<=count($ingname);$i++)

Comment: what you need to do is take out the query and pdo stuff and just echo out the sql queries in the for loop and see if you get all the ones you should. then go back in and add the database stuff.

Comment: Same goes for amount and measurement. The array picks up all of the values, but then the array repeats for the amount of values entered.

Comment: I just want to thank you, @FunkDoc for all of your help! I got it to work based off of your feedback. I appreciate it more than you know!

Comment: Cheers! Sorry it was a bit brutal there. You'll get used to this stuff as you move forward. Happy coding!